# Stored procedure returned unknown execution result Unknown

Tags: wcf, workflow-foundation-4

I'm getting the below error when calling a Workflow Service hosted on your staging environment.

```
Stored procedure returned unknown execution result Unknown.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message) 

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at IWorkflow.InvokeWorkflowRequest(String id)
   at WorkflowClient.InvokeWorkflowRequest(String id)
```

My configuration file

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WorkflowService">
       <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="IWorkflow"  />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <sqlWorkflowInstanceStore connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Store;Integrated Security=True;Asynchronous Processing=True"  />
      </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Locally the service works fine and even when pointing to my staging DB. I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: search for the place you throw the exception: Stored procedure returned unknown execution result Unknown. It is not likely the .net framework throws the exception, because you are the only hit in google. I guess your staging evironment has a faulty db configuration.

Comment: Thanks, for your responds. I'll hear from the DBA's maybe they can see something.

Comment: I dropped the database run bat file to recreate database instance and it works. Thanks, again.

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem with Workflow Foundation 4.5 when a new instance was persisted without DefinitionIdentity.

An exception 'Stored procedure returned unknown execution result Unknown' was thrown and no inner exception was given.

The exception was thrown because SaveInstance procedure was returning 99 and was caused by a missing row in table [System.Activities.DurableInstancing].[DefinitionIdentityTable].

You can recreate the missing row with the following sql script :

> INSERT [System.Activities.DurableInstancing].[DefinitionIdentityTable]
>   ([SurrogateIdentityId], [DefinitionIdentityHash],
>   [DefinitionIdentityAnyRevisionHash], [Name], [Package], [Build],
>   [Major], [Minor], [Revision]) VALUES (1,
>   N'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
>   N'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
>   NULL)

I hope it helps someone

Answer (score 0):

This problem might also arise if the persistence DB is out of memory. Got it today and the solution was to extend the persistence DB available space.